# Joining Table with substring condition

Tags: mysql, join, substring, outer-join

I Have two tables :

```
create table t1(
id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
group varchar(3) not null,
number int unsigned zerofill,
used enum('YES','NO') default );

id   group   number  used
1    '110'   00001   'YES'
2    '110'   00002   'YES'
3    '110'   00003   'YES'
4    '210'   00001   'YES'
5    '210'   00002   'YES'
6    '210'   00003   'YES'
7    '310'   00001   'YES'

create table t2(
id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
number varchar(13) default null);

id   number  
1    '110-00001'
2    '110-00002'
3    '210-00002'
4    '310-00001'
```

My First Goal is to find every record from t1 that not used in t2:

query result :

```
id   group   number  used
3    '110'   00003   'YES'
4    '210'   00001   'YES'
6    '210'   00003   'YES'
```

And my 2nd Goal is to Set the column used to be 'NO':

```
id   group   number  used
3    '110'   00003   'NO'
4    '210'   00001   'NO'
6    '210'   00003   'NO'
```

I have tried to use the query like this :

```
  select * from t1 
left outer join t2 
             on t1.number = cast(substring(t2.number,8,5) as int) 
          where t2.id is null;
```

but mySQL says:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'int) where tblpeserta.id is null

is there a better query for my problem?!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `CAST(SUBSTRING(t2.number,8,5) AS UNSIGNED)`? Actually, I'm not quite sure why do you need cast here.

Comment: because number in t1 is a int zerofill and number in t2 is varchar, so i need to convert it to int so the t1.number and t2.number can be compared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE t1 LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.`group` = LEFT(t2.number, 3)
   AND t1.number = 0 + RIGHT(t2.number, 5)
   SET t1.used = 'NO'
 WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

and SELECT

```
SELECT *
  FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t1.`group` = LEFT(t2.number, 3)
   AND t1.number = 0 + RIGHT(t2.number, 5)
 WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Output:

```
| ID | GROUP | NUMBER | USED |
------------------------------
|  3 |   110 |      3 |   NO |
|  4 |   210 |      1 |   NO |
|  6 |   210 |      3 |   NO |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/101ec/3)**