# MySQL join 2 tables A,B by id, where A.id is a substring of B.id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, 'Node' and 'Equipment'

The Node Table has node id, name, and function. Each node is full of equipment, given in the Equipment table. The equipment id contains the node id + equipment designation text. So the node id is a substring of the equipment id. I want to be able to query what equipment a node has by using the node id in the equipment table.

How can I structure a query to:

"Join the tables given the node id, Add the node longName column entry to each piece of equipment in the equipment table containing the node id (within its equipment id)"

Edit: This is not a duplicate question as it relies on the use of "LIKE", which was not present in the other linked answer

```
Node table
+--------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
| id                                   | longName   | memberFunction |
+--------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995 | North_Node | DGE            |
| 182019b4-b2e7-307b-85c6-2a39001a54ff | South_Node | DGE            |
| 1adf96c7-8e0d-35d9-9d00-1c0acf6c6f92 | East_Node  | ROADM          |
| 1d14064f-6bd9-3d11-862f-abc25612d88f | West_Node  | ILA            |
+--------------------------------------+------------+----------------+
```

```
Equipment table
+----------------------------------------------------+-------+------+
| id                                                 | shelf | slot |
+----------------------------------------------------+-------+------+
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21      |    21 | NULL |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_1    |    21 |    1 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_10   |    21 |   10 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_10_2 |    21 |   10 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_11   |    21 |   11 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_13   |    21 |   13 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_14   |    21 |   14 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_14_2 |    21 |   14 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_15   |    21 |   15 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_16   |    21 |   16 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_17_1 |    21 |   17 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_17_2 |    21 |   17 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_17_3 |    21 |   17 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_1_2  |    21 |    1 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_2    |    21 |    2 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_3    |    21 |    3 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_5    |    21 |    5 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_6    |    21 |    6 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_7    |    21 |    7 |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_9    |    21 |    9 |
........................
```

```
Desired output table
+----------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------------+
| id                                                 | shelf | slot | longName   |
+----------------------------------------------------+-------+------+------------+
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21      |    21 | NULL | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_1    |    21 |    1 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_10   |    21 |   10 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_10_2 |    21 |   10 | North_Node | 
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_11   |    21 |   11 | North_Node | 
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_13   |    21 |   13 | North_Node | 
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_14   |    21 |   14 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_14_2 |    21 |   14 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_15   |    21 |   15 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_16   |    21 |   16 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_17_1 |    21 |   17 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_17_2 |    21 |   17 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_17_3 |    21 |   17 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_1_2  |    21 |    1 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_2    |    21 |    2 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_3    |    21 |    3 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_5    |    21 |    5 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_6    |    21 |    6 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_7    |    21 |    7 | North_Node |
| 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_9    |    21 |    9 | North_Node |
.............................................
```

Comment: Ideally fix and normalize the schema and split the `id` of `equipment` into two columns one just holding that UUID. That way you'll not only be able to create a foreign key constraint to ensure referential integrity, but to simply join on an `=`. Maybe normalize even further and get rid of that `'EQPT_<n>_<m>...'` stuff entirely. Instead introduce a column for the optional third number. Then it can always be created from `shelf`, `slot` and that number. You then have no more dependencies in a row that can cause inconsistencies.

Comment: @sticky bit, that would be ideal however I can't change the column names or data as this comes straight from an API, and the background to pass into MySQL has used the API response dictionary keys as column names to save a tonne of work at that level

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining Table with substring condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630466/joining-table-with-substring-condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
select n.*, e.*
from nodes n join
     equipment e
     on n.id = substring_instr(e.id, ':', 1);
```

A second method is

```
select n.*, e.*
from nodes n join
     equipment e
     on e.id = concat(n.id, '::%');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select
  e.*,
  n.longName
from Equipment e
join Node n on e.id like concat(n.id, '%')
```

Comment: Accepted @Gordon Linoff answer as the id length is not fixed, so this will handle all variants of the id in my case

Answer (score 1):

A simple join is enough

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Node (
>   `id` VARCHAR(36),
>   `longName` VARCHAR(10),
>   `memberFunction` VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Node
>   (`id`, `longName`, `memberFunction`)
> VALUES
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995', 'North_Node', 'DGE'),
>   ('182019b4-b2e7-307b-85c6-2a39001a54ff', 'South_Node', 'DGE'),
>   ('1adf96c7-8e0d-35d9-9d00-1c0acf6c6f92', 'East_Node', 'ROADM'),
>   ('1d14064f-6bd9-3d11-862f-abc25612d88f', 'West_Node', 'ILA');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Equipmen (
>   `id` VARCHAR(50),
>   `shelf` INTEGER,
>   `slot` VARCHAR(4)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Equipmen
>   (`id`, `shelf`, `slot`)
> VALUES
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21', '21', 'NULL'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_1', '21', '1'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_10', '21', '10'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_10_2', '21', '10'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_11', '21', '11'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_13', '21', '13'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_14', '21', '14'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_14_2', '21', '14'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_15', '21', '15'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_16', '21', '16'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_17_1', '21', '17'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_17_2', '21', '17'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_17_3', '21', '17'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_1_2', '21', '1'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_2', '21', '2'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_3', '21', '3'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_5', '21', '5'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_6', '21', '6'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_7', '21', '7'),
>   ('15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_9', '21', '9');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT e.*,n.`longName` 
> FROM Equipmen e INNER JOIN Node n ON n.id = LEFT(e.id,36)
> ```
>
> ```
> id                                                 | shelf | slot | longName  
> :------------------------------------------------- | ----: | :--- | :---------
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21      |    21 | NULL | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_1    |    21 | 1    | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_10   |    21 | 10   | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_10_2 |    21 | 10   | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_11   |    21 | 11   | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_13   |    21 | 13   | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_14   |    21 | 14   | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_14_2 |    21 | 14   | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_15   |    21 | 15   | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_16   |    21 | 16   | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_17_1 |    21 | 17   | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_17_2 |    21 | 17   | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_17_3 |    21 | 17   | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_1_2  |    21 | 1    | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_2    |    21 | 2    | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_3    |    21 | 3    | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_5    |    21 | 5    | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_6    |    21 | 6    | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_7    |    21 | 7    | North_Node
> 15c6a1ef-ff1c-3486-bce9-8157906a2995::EQPT_21_9    |    21 | 9    | North_Node
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=81fe5cf781401954024ed437082b2c4f)*